# What is the best way to prevent a field from being editable at a certain value?

Tags: validation-rule, edit

I have a checkbox that I would like to not be un-checked once it's been checked. I've accomplished this by putting in a Validation Rule.

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Field__c),PriorValue(Field__c) = True)
```

But is there an even simpler way of doing it ? Preferably by making it appear un-editable once it's =TRUE ?

I'm starting to think of different ways, but they are all more complicated than a simple validation rule. I've got to be overlooking something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via Dynamic Forms. You can now control the behaviour of the fields rather than simply hiding or showing the fields.

To achieve this, you'd need to include the field twice and update the filters to only show that instance of the field if it is true or false like this:

[image]

I would still recommend having the Validation Rule in place however, as this will only impact it at a UI level for users and isn't going to enforce the behaviour if they use another method to update the record.

Comment: I didn't notice the addition of extra UI behaviour changes. Nice option.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

1. Using dynamic forms, you could have the field become invisible once set true, but this would be troublesome at the time of editing it.
2. Using a quick action. Make sure the field is read only in the page always, for everyone (you can do that in a page layout), and add a flow-based quick action that allows it to be set (not unset).